# How to make Tcl loop variable exist just within the loop, akin to Perl foreach my

Tags: variables, for-loop, scope, closures, tcl

See Tcl shell code & results below:

```
% foreach a { 1 2 3 4 5 } { puts $a }
1
2
3
4
5
% puts $a
5
```

It would appear that variable a stays in the memory... In Perl, for example one can use:

```
foreach my $a
```

And have $a exist just during the looping. in Ruby, one can use closures:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each{|a| puts a.to_s() }
```

In order to achieve the same.
Is there an elegant way to this in Tcl?
Thanks

Comment: As of now, there is no in-built mechanism for this. You can explicitly use `unset` command to achieve the same after the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am using now (clutter minimization).

Comment: Or, you can override the `foreach` command's behavior with `rename` and do the `unset` operation for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate within a closure:

```
apply {vals {foreach a $vals {puts $a}}} {1 2 3 4 5}
```

alternatively you can make the body a parameter (in which case the looping variable’s name should be a parameter too):

```
apply {{varName vals body} {foreach $varName $vals $body}} a {1 2 3 4 5} {puts $a}
```

If you call this `myForeach` or something, it looks less cumbersome:

```
set myForeach {{varName vals body} {foreach $varName $vals $body}}
apply $myForeach a {1 2 3 4 5} {puts $a}
```

You can also make this an interpreter macro:

```
set myForeach {{varName vals body} {foreach $varName $vals $body}}
interp alias {} myForeach {} apply $myForeach
myForeach a {1 2 3 4 5} {puts $a}
```

Documentation: [apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [interp](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/interp/tcllib_interp.html) package, [interp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/interp.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the current semantics of `foreach`, and this is *extremely* unlikely to change in the near future as it would have a severe impact on many people's existing code. In particular, many people currently use:

```
foreach {a b c d} $someList break
```

Instead of doing:

```
lassign $someList a b c d
```

Because that was what worked in Tcl 8.4 and before and they've not updated their coding style since.